# How can an ObservableList<T> be sorted in Dart?

Tags: dart, observable, dart-polymer, polymer

I can't seem to sort an `ObservableList<T>` and have the sort reflected in my Polymer element. Here's a sample element definition:

```dart
class PeopleElement extends PolymerElement {
  ObservableList<Person> people = toObservable(new List<Person>());

  PeopleElement.created() : super.created();
}
```

And here is the definition of the `Person` class:

```dart
class Person {
  String name;
  Person(this.name);

  int compare(Person p) {
    return name.compareTo(p.name);
  }
}
```

Now, I want to add a `sort` function to the `PeopleElement` class:

```dart
class PeopleElement extends PolymerElement {
  ...

  ObservableList<Person> sortByName() {
    people.sort((Person a, Person b) {
      a.compare(b);
    }
  }
}
```

I've also tried the above function as returning `void` and that didn't seem to work either. Does anything jump out as being incorrect here?

Comment: Is it the missing `return` before `a.compare(b)`?

Comment: @FlorianLoitsch That shouldn't be necessary, because the `compare` function returns an `int` by definition. And so `return` would be redundant in that case.

Comment: Not really, no. The anonymous function passed to sort does not have a return statement. You need to write it as "(a, b)=>a.compare(b)" or "(a, b) { return a.compare(b); }", but as written it only ever returns null.

Comment: @lrn I figured that out yesterday. You're absolutely right. I'm tempted to file a bug, because that syntax is very confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Person` class needs to implement `Comparable` with the method `compareTo` instead of `compare`

```dart
library people_element;

import 'dart:async';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

class Person implements Comparable{
  String name;
  Person(this.name);

  @override
  int compareTo(Person other) {
    return name.compareTo(other.name);
  }
}

@CustomTag('people-element')
class PeopleElement extends PolymerElement {
  var people = toObservable(new List<Person>());

  PeopleElement.created() : super.created() {
    print('PeopleElement');
  }

  @override
  void enteredView() {
    people.add(new Person('c'));
    people.add(new Person('a'));
    people.add(new Person('f'));
    people.add(new Person('b'));

    super.enteredView();

    new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 3), () => sortByName());
  }

  ObservableList<Person> sortByName() {
    people.sort();
  }
}


<polymer-element name="people-element">
  <template>

    <template repeat="{{p in people}}">
      <p>{{p.name}}</p>
    </template>

  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="people_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: I did manage to find a solution on my own (it turns that I a syntactical bug that I wasn't aware of). But this solution strikes me as more elegant.